# eclipse not running maven build using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have observed this in Spring tool suite as well as with Eclipse.

If I fire up the IDE - I cannot use shortcuts to run maven build.
( alt + shift + X + M ) 
The context menu shows up and it also seems as if the build has been fired - but console indicates that it has not.

To get around this - the first time eclipse is loaded - I do the build manually ( right click on project - Run as - maven install )

Note once I do this - the keyboard shortcuts to build work fine .

Is this a bug or an incorrect user understanding ?

Comment: Hit Strg+Shift+L to check, if the shortcut is available and not overridden.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with Eclipse Photon (4.8) and M2E 1.9.1. Please note, the shortcut is a sequence of keystrokes: Alt+Shif+X followed by M. Do you mean by _"context menu"_ the dialog that is displayed when waiting too long between the two keystrokes and which shows all key sequences starting with Alt+Shif+X?

Comment: That is correct - after Alt+Shift+X you get a menu on the right will all the options.I am using Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.3. Using maven version 3.2.5. Note this only happens when you start eclipse the first time - after the first build using the menu - then the build using shortcut works fine